# Parity Development Chain

Tags: parity, dapp-development, testnets, kovan

I am new to parity and wanted clarity on the clarity `development chain`

Is it like testrpc ie. stored in local and not like the testnets (ropsten, kovan and rinkeby) which are simulation blockchains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *private* development chain is only a local blockchain-development environment unless you add additional peers.

Ropsten, Kovan, and Rinkeby are *public* testnets shared with other developers.